# What is the right way to change the title color of a Filled styled UIButton programatically?

Tags: ios, swift

Change the title color of a **Default** styled button programmatically is straightforward.

[image]

We just need to perform

```
button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

But, what about a **Filled** styled button?

[image]

Using 1 liner `UIButton.setTitleColor` has no effect.

After several trial and error, I have came out with an "ugly" way

```
if let configuration = button.configuration {
    let attributedStringColor = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red];

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(
        string: button.titleLabel?.text ?? "",
        attributes: attributedStringColor
    )

    do {
        let a = try AttributedString(attributedString, including: \.uiKit)
        
        var c = configuration
        
        c.attributedTitle = a
        
        button.configuration = c
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Even though that works, I just feel it is not the right way, to require so many lines of code to change the button title color.

May I know, what is the right way to change the title color of a Filled styled UIButton programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a neat little extension to AttributeContainer:

```
extension AttributeContainer {
    init(foregroundColor: UIColor) {
        self.init()
        self.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
    }
}
```

And then use it to set the button's title and color:

```
button.configuration = .filled()
button.configuration?.attributedTitle = AttributedString("ButtonTitle", attributes: .init(foregroundColor: .systemRed))
```

..or you can just do this:

```
button.configuration?.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor = .systemRed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.baseForegroundColor` configuration property:

```
var cfg = tintedBtn.configuration
cfg?.baseForegroundColor = .red
tintedBtn.configuration = cfg
```